# Need help plot 1 to n y-series with matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I have a problem that the user of my script want to be able to print 1 - n graphs of the type account (ex 1930,1940 etc) and the sum for every account for every year.

The graph I want to plot should look like this (in this ex 2 accounts(1930 and 1940) and sum for every account for every year):

[image]

The input for the graph printing is like this (The user of the script should be able to choose as many accounts as the user wants 1-n):

```
How many accounts to print graphs for? 2
Account 1 :
1930
Account 2 :
1940
```

The system will store the Accounts in an array (`accounts = [1930,1940]`
) and look up the sum for every account for every year. The years and sum for the accounts are placed in a `matrix ([[2008, 1, 12], [2009, 7, 30], [2010, 13, 48], [2011, 19, 66], [2012, 25, 84], [2013, 31, 102]])`.

When this is done I want to plot 1 - n graphs (in this case 2 graphs). But I can't figure out how to plot with 1 - n accounts...

For the moment I just use this code to print the graph and it's just static :(:

```
#fix the x serie
x_years = []
for i in range (nrOfYearsInXML):
    x_years.append(matrix[x][0])
    x = x + 1
plt.xticks(x_years, map(str,x_years))

#fix the y series, how to solve the problem if the user shows 1 - n accounts?

1930_sum = [1, 7, 13, 19, 25, 31]
1940_sum = [12, 30, 48, 66, 84, 102]

plt.plot(x_years, konto1_summa, marker='o', label='1930')
plt.plot(x_years, konto2_summa, marker='o', label='1940')
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Summa')
plt.title('Sum for account per year')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Ok, so I have tried with for loops etc, but I have not been able to figure it out with 1-n accounts and an unique account label to 1-n accounts..

My scenario is that the user choose 1 - n accounts. Specify the accounts (ex 1930,1940,1950..). Store the accounts to an array. System calculate the sum for 1-n account for every year and place this data to the matrix. System when reads from the accounts array and the matrix and plot 1-n graphs. Every graph with account label.

**A shorter version of the problem...**

For example if I have the x values (the years 2008-2013) and the y values (the sum for the accounts for every year) in a matrix and the accounts(should also be used as label) in an array like this:

```
accounts = [1930,1940]
matrix = [[2008, 1, 12], [2009, 7, 30], [2010, 13, 48], [2011, 19, 66], [2012, 25, 84], [2013, 31, 102]]
```

Or I can explain x and y like this:

```
x       y1(1930 graph1)     y2(1940 graph2)
2008        1               12
2009        7               30
2010        13              48
etc         etc             etc
```

The problem for me is that the user can choose one to many accounts (accounts [1..n]) and this will result in 1 to many account graphs.

Any idea how to solve it.. :)?

BR/M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you are asking, but I *think* this is what you want:

```
# set up axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.set_xlabel('xlab')
ax.set_ylabel('ylab')

# loop and plot
for j in range(n):
    x, y = get_data(n) # what ever function you use to get your data
    lab = get_label(n)
    ax.plot(x, y, label=lab)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

More concretely, assuming you have the matrix structure you posted above:

```
# first, use numpy, you have it installed anyway if matplotlib is working
# and it will make your life much nicer
data = np.array(data_list_of_lists)
x = data[:,0]
for j in range(n):
    y = data[:, j+1]
    ax.plot(x, y, lab=accounts[j])
```

A better way to do this is to store your data in a `dict`

```
data_dict[1940] = (x_data_1940, y_data_1940)
data_dict[1930] = (x_data_1930, y_data_1930)
# ...

for k in acounts:
     x,y = data_dict[k]
     ax.plot(x, y, lab=k)
```

Comment: thx for helping, I tried to add a shorter version of the problem in my question, look under "A shorter version of the problem..."

Comment: @martin Which part of this are you having trouble with?  Any solution is going to be a slight variation on this.

Comment: the problem is that I do not know how I should solve the implementation with for loops if the array accounts[] will change from 1 to many accounts. Fyi, I re-worked and played around with your code a bit.. But I could not get it to plot the y values...

Comment: @martin See edits.  I would also suggest that you (re)read  http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/ as you seem to be having some issues with the basics.

Comment: thx, I will check into this. Yes, I'm both new to python and matplotlib, I usually take care of the economics...;)

Comment: I checked your soloution with the np.array, but the graph will turn out a bit strange... I do not understand why define x before the for loop, every time you plot x you will have the same value for x. Using the code I will first time in loop plot x = `[2008    1   12]` y = `[2009    7   30]`. Second time in loop plot x = `[2008    1   12]` y = `[2010   13   48]` etc... Thx for helping.

Comment: @martin gah! I messed up the order of the slicing sorry about that.  See edit (`x` should now be `[2008, 2009, ...]`)

Comment: Wow, tested it now and it works :)!! Really, thx for helping! I'm so happy now :)!!